# Firebase firestore security rules for public and private collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have 2 collections `subscribers` and `posts`. I have setup the security rules to be `read: write when authenticated`. But i need the `subscribers` collection to write the data without authentication and in `posts` collection to check the authentication and then write  How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set firestore rules and you can test them in the firebase simulator as well.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /subscribers/{document=**} {
      allow read, write : if true;
    }
    match /posts/{document=**} {
      allow read : if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

The answer is quite specific to the words of your question that you want to write the data when authenticated for `posts` collection. I've considered that reading data is still open to all.

Comment: Working.. but let say i have multiple collections and i only need `subscribers` to be `write: if true`. Do i have to write ` match /posts/{document=**} {
      allow read : if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }` this to every other collections?

Comment: If u have multiple databases, you have to write separate rules for each one of them. But if you have multiple collections, you need not write anything for other collections if u don't want any db rules to be applied to them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it -

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /subscribers/{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
    match /posts/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```